# Create view to select different tables based on current schema

Tags: oracle, view

So I have two similar tables in two different schemas eg. schema1.TableA and schema2.TableA.
From my application, there are two other schemas which have select access to these two tables.
Is it possible to create a view such that when the current schema is Schema3 then that view should return data from schema1.TableA whereas when the current schema is Schema4 then the view should return data from schema2.TableA?
Or is there any other way to achieve this in oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Grant permissions to select from the schema to the appropriate users and then create synonyms for each user:

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA1.TABLEA TO SCHEMA3;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA2.TABLEA TO SCHEMA4;
CREATE SYNONYM schema3.tableA FOR SCHEMA1.tableA;
CREATE SYNONYM schema4.tableA FOR SCHEMA2.tableA;
```

Then you should be able to use `SELECT * FROM tableA` as `schema3` and `schema4` and it will get the data from the appropriate table/view in each schema.